# What is good way to achieve formatting via clang-format?

Tags: c++, formatting, clang-format

All

Formatting C++ code, reasonable happy with what clang-format produced, except two things:

How could I make colon to be on the same line as constructor? INstead of

```
Detector::Detector()
     : _LogicTarget{nullptr},
```

I would like to get

```
Detector::Detector():
    _LogicTarget{nullptr},
```

Second question, could I remove break after access modifier?

```
public:
    void f();
```

should be

```
public: void f();
```

Comment: Have you tried other formats?  The clang-format manual shows at least 4 other formats ... maybe one of those does what you need.   2nd Q - what did the manual say?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN `Have you tried other formats?` what do you mean other formats? I've dumped WebKit and hacking it. Wrt Q2 it seems answer is `no`, access modifiers do not have break option

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux From  "Clang 3.9 documentation, Clang-Format Style Options", 1)  LLVM A style complying with the LLVM coding standards  2)  Google A style complying with Google’s C++ style guide 3)  Chromium A style complying with Chromium’s style guide 4)  Mozilla A style complying with Mozilla’s style guide  5) WebKit A style complying with WebKit’s style guide.  It reads like you can start with one of these, and touch it.  Perhaps I stumbled upon something un-related.  Sorry.

Comment: Regarding your first question: there is no option to not break before the colon (or I'm relly missing something). It was the only thing keeping me from using clang-format and so I looked into the code and added an option to keep the colon on the same line. I didn't submit it as a patch because it might not play well with other options, but it does the job for me. I can post it as an answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by setting

```
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine : true
```

Then output will be

```
Detector::Detector():
    _LogicTarget{nullptr}
```

and

```
public: void f();
```